# Creating an additional partition on MBR partitioned drive with data on it

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr

I have an external 500GB HDD which already has data on it, there is currently one partition on the drive but I need to create a new one on this drive with at least 10GB of space. I've already used 460GB on the drive but would like to make a new 10-15GB Partition in order to create a boot disk to restore another Mac.

Is it possible to create a second partition which doesn't erase the existing data which is partitioned with MBR?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, partitioning can easily be done in Windows 7.

1. Click `Start`
2. Right click `Computer`
3. Click `Manage`
4. Click `Disk Management`
5. Right click your 500GB disk at bottom of screen. (Right click the space in use).
6. Click `Shrink volume`
7. Follow wizard to shrink the 500 down to your required size (485GB to give 15GB free space).

I'm concerned that when you use the space and make it bootable that you don't run into problems with your Windows partition/startup... The MBR contains the partition information on a disk. The new partition created doesn't have its own MBR... If you set your Mac partition to bootable then Windows probably won't boot.

Comment: If it's possible, backup your data ! Changing partitions on a disk can always lead to data loss if something goes wrong. If there is a power loss, or a BSoD happens, you'll have a hard time recovering your data.
Here it is an external HDD with data, so no problem booting on it.
If the Windows 7 utility can't do that, Gparted can help: http://gparted.org/ .

Comment: Thanks for the "external" reminder! I got so into writing the instructions that I forgot it was simply a data disk. As piernov says, you can set the new Mac partition to bootable and (all going well) you should be able to boot to it. You're using a Mac style partition on the unallocated space so you will need to look at the Mac way of making it so read up on what you need to do. I can't help with that I'm afraid!

Comment: And I didn't read the "Mac" part… I don't know if a Mac boot disk needs a GPT or MBR works too, and if it will work if it's not the 1st partition on the disk.